# Interactive input in python

Tags: python

Here is the directions for what I need to do:

You are to write a complete program that obtains three pieces of data and then process them. The three pieces of information are a Boolean value, a string, and an integer. The logic of the program is this: if the Boolean value is True, print out the string twice, once with double quotes and once without - otherwise print out twice the number.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    Boolean = input("Give me a Boolean: ")
    String = input("Give me a string: ")
    Number = int(input("Give me a number: "))
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately we don't just do your hw here. Please show us some effort and if along the way you need help with something specific we'll gladly help you out.

Answer (score 3):

On stackoverflow, we're here to help people solve problems, not to do your homework, as your question very likely sounds… That said, here is what you want:

```
def main():
    Boolean = input("Give me a Boolean: ")
    String = input("Give me a string: ")
    Number = int(input("Give me a number: "))

    if Boolean == "True":
        print('"{s}"\n{s}'.format(s=String))
    try:
        print('{}\n{}'.format(int(Number)))
    except ValueError as err:
        print('Error you did not give a number: {}'.format(err))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

A few explanations:

- `Boolean is "True"` checks whether the contained string is actually the word `True`, and returns `True`, `False` otherwise.
- then the `print(''.format())` builds the double string (separated by `\n`) using the string format.
- finally, when converting the string `Integer` into an `int` using `int(Integer)`, it will raise a `ValueError` exception that gets caught to display a nice message on error.

the `if __name__ == "__main__":` part is to enable your code to be only executed when ran as a script, not when imported as a library. That's the pythonic way of defining the program's entry point.

Comment: of course, I actually tried first `bool(Boolean) is True` first, and then saw that it was stupid… And forgot to amend the `is`.

Answer (score 0):

I like to add a bit of logic to ensure proper values when I do input.
My standard way is like this:

```
import ast
def GetInput(user_message, var_type = str):
    while 1:
        # ask the user for an input
        str_input = input(user_message + ": ")
        # you dont need to cast a string!
        if var_type == str:
            return str_input
        else:
            input_type = type(ast.literal_eval(str_input))
        if var_type == input_type:
            return ast.literal_eval(str_input)
        else:
            print("Invalid type! Try again!")
```

Then in your main you can do something like this!

```
def main():
    my_bool = False
    my_str = ""
    my_num = 0
    my_bool = GetInput("Give me a Boolean", type(my_bool))
    my_str = GetInput("Give me a String", type(my_str))
    my_num = GetInput("Give me a Integer", type(my_num))

    if my_bool:
        print('"{}"'.format(my_str))
        print(my_str)
    else:
        print(my_num * 2)
```